# How to avoid ignore tests if I use inner classes for unit testing architecting?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, inner-classes, runner

I have following architecture of unit test:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class ProductTest {

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public static abstract class Base {...}

    public static class Test1 extends Base{
        @Test
        public void foo(){...}
        }
    }

    public static class Test2 extends Base{
        @Test
        public void bar(){...}
        }
    }
}
```

If I run unit tests I see following error message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 

No tests found in Base
Haven't you forgot @Test annotation?
```

Mockito tries to say me that `Base` is test bit have noone method annoted with `@Test`

I have found decision - ignore base class.

Bit it looks like hack. Is there more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Base` outside the `ProductTest` class (can be in same file) and move `RunWith` to concrete classes.

Comment: Please, see following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475003/mockito-java-lang-exception-class-should-be-public-when-i-use-inner-classes-in