# Mockito java.lang.Exception: Class should be public when I use inner classes in tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, inner-classes

I have following  test:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class ProductTest {

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    @Ignore
    public static abstract class Base1 {
        @Before
        public void setUpBase()  {...}
    }

    public static class Test1 extends Base1{
        @Test
        public void foo(){...}
        }
    }

    public static class Test2 extends Base1{
        @Test
        public void bar(){...}
        }
    }
}
```

---

To avoid `@Ignore` I refactored class like this:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class ProductTest {

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public static class Test1 extends Base1 {
        @Test
        public void foo() {...}
    }

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public static class Test2 extends Base1 {
        @Test
        public void bar() {...}
    }
}

abstract class Base1 {
    @Before
    public void setUpBase()  {...}
}
```

But I see error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Class Base1 should be public
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoid(FrameworkMethod.java:91)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:133)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:165)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.<init>(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:23)
```

1.Please clarify me cause of the problem
2.Please advise me elegant way to avoid following error.

I want to encapsulate logic in one file.

Comment: Running JUnit 4.12 / java 8, with both snippet the error is not reproducible. Your question is not very clear as what is supposed to be encapsulated.

Anyway just looking at the error message it's fairly straightforward to understand that the public visibility of class `Base1` is the issue and that this class have a package visibility in your second snippet.

Comment: **1.** I use java 6 **2.** Same file cannot contains 2 public classes

Comment: Have you tried marking `Base1` with `@Ignore`? Does that cause the concrete classes to be ignored?

Comment: Have you tried where `Base` is an inner class but the `RunWith` is on the concrete classes?

Comment: Another option, do you REALLY need a base class? Could you put the common methods in `ProductTest`? I have also used a pattern where the test classes encapsulate another inner class that extends `ExternalResource`. This works fine.

Comment: **Have you tried marking Base1 with @Ignore?** - yes, but I don't like this decision

Comment: **Does that cause the concrete classes to be ignored?** unclear question for me.

Comment: **Running JUnit 4.12 / java 8** - Running JUnit 4.11 / java 6

Comment: **Could you put the common methods in ProductTest? I** it is really works fine

Comment: @John B but it break modularity

Comment: Per `cause to be ignored`: if the base class is marked with `@Ignore` does that result in the concrete classes being ignored?

Comment: When it comes to tests, I don't worry too much about perfect design as long as I don't have repeated code. Perfect is the enemy of good enough and these are tests not production code.

Comment: sonar complains about ignored tests)

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). To help rule that out, perhaps you can explain the problem you are trying to solve by using all those inner test classes.

Comment: Can you explain why **Class Base1 should be public** ?

Comment: @Duncan On our project uses mentioned architecture style for writing unit tests. I cannot change this style. Now I got a task to avoid ignore tests

Comment: Junit requires that test classes must be public. As @gstackoverflow mentioned, one java file cannot have two public classes. But you can try to make Base1 a public static class inside ProductTest class (move it to its body), this should work.

Comment: And after this action we will return to initial question or I didn't catch something?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue recently and I solved the issue by changing the class to public class. You might need to check if your `Class Base1` is indeed a public class.

Answer (score -1):

1. The cause of the problem is that your test class template is over engineered.
2. The most elegant way I know of to avoid the error is to refactor your test class like this (I have omitted @RunWith annotation because I don't know what the correct one is):

   ```
   public class ProductTest {
       @Before
       public void setUpBase()  {...}

       @Test
       public void foo(){...}

       @Test
       public void bar(){...}
   }
   ```

In your implementation, having each test in it's own class is unnecessary because JUnit will create multiple instances of ProductTest anyway - so each test is isolated from all the others without having to be in it's own class.